# Adding <option> element to <select> along with id dynamically and use that added id

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with 3 drop downs by selecting the first option in drop down1 the drop down2 gets filled with the options dynamically so far so good. But while selecting the option in the second drop down the problem occurs the third drop down not filling up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#st").click(function() {
        $("#ds").html('<option id="dsp">1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>');
    });

    $("#dsp").click(function() {

        $("#plc").html('<option>1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>');
        alert("hi");
    });


});
</script>

<title>TODO supply a title</title>

</head>
<body>
<select>
    <option id="st">1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="ds">

</select>

<select id="plc">

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your markup the `id` is *ds*, but in your jQuery code it is *dsp*: `$("#dsp").click`

Comment: @abhitalks It's there, he is adding it from JavaScript: `$("#ds").html('<option id="dsp">...`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Yup. I was confused. That's why the comment. Thanks for pointing out though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use change like this

```js
$("#first").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).children(":selected").attr("id") == 'st') {
    $("#ds").html('<option id="dsp">1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>');
  }
});

$("#ds").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).children(":selected").attr("id") == 'dsp') {
    $("#plc").html('<option>1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>');
  }
});
$("#plc").on('change', function() {
  alert("This Works");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="first">
  <option id="st">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="ds"></select>
<select id="plc"></select>
```

Comment: Yes. This is better. But, please no `id` on `option`. Use its `value` instead.

Comment: whats the reason to use on() in your code what does it specify?

Comment: As per jQuery Documentation "Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.". Read about it here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind (click)-events to dynamically added elements, you should use:

`$('[parent-element]').on('click', '[target-element]', function() {
    // do something
});`

Which would result in something like

`$('#ds').on('click', '#dsp', function() {
    // do something
});`

Because the selector won't recognize the element with the `$([element/id/class])` method.

Comment: Read the code, #dsp is the id of the option he wants to add in the second select :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you add items to the DOM, you will need to additionally set the event handlers.

So when the item gets added, you need to re-add the click handler as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#st").click(function() {
            $("#ds").html('<option id="dsp">1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>');
            $("#dsp").click(function() {

                $("#plc").html('<option>1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>');
                alert("hi");
            });
        });           
    });
```

Comment: You need to read the question more carefully (`dsp` is added dynamically). Also this should be a comment as it does not answer the question.

Comment: You're right.. changed the answer to reflect that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event on the `select` to run your code. Also, specify `id` on `select`, not on `option`.

*JQuery*:

```
$("#st").on("change", function() {
    ...
});

$("#ds").on("change", function() {
    ...
});
```

*HTML*:

```
<select id="st">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="ds">
..
</select>

<select id="plc">
..
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IDs on `option` elements, it is better to use the values. And if, the user changes the value back to one that's not the target value, you want the next `select` to be repopulated. Finally you want the selects to load **RIGHT** at page load -- use `.change()` on the first and second.

The `change` event on the `select` is what you need to use, not the `click`event:

```js
$("#first").on('change', function() {
    $("#ds").html( this.value === '1' ? '<option>1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>' : '');
})
.change();

$("#ds").on('change', function() {
    $("#plc").html(this.value === '1' ? '<option>1</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>' : '');
})
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="first">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="ds"></select>
<select id="plc"></select>
```